# Clickonce application does not work as scheduled after sign off on Windows server

Tags: clickonce

I prepared a .bat file and wrote the clickonce applicaiton reference file path (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\HarmonyClient\ClickClient.appref-ms).
Then I created a task from the task scheduler to run every hour and referenced this .bat file.
It works manually on the server, it works in the case of a sign on per hour, but it does not work when the server restarts or when the user signout.

When I try the same process on Windows 10 client, it works when restart and signoff, but when I do the same actions on the server, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know anything about this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Answer (score 0):

If the server that Clickonce is installed is restarted , scheduled Clickonce application does not work because the user does not have a logon. Therefore, if automatic logon is performed with this user, the problem is solved.
There are 2 ways to automatically logon a windows user.

1. Manually performing the operations at Registery(regedit.exe).
   You can show this link
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon in
2. Automatically performing the operations in the Register (regedit.exe) with the sysinternals autologon program. This program is from microsoft and also keeps the user password encrypted. You can download it from the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon